# All strings in a range with a given prefix and suffix

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, string-matching

Given a decimal number N (which has at most, 10^6 digits, actually we should look at it as a string!) and another decimal number M (which has K digits, 1 <= K <= 10^6 ), we are asked to find all number in range (1, N) where K first digits and k last digits of that number looks like M.

I try the following method (on paper actually).

If N, has for example, n digits:

1- consider all numbers with n-1 digits. if (n-1) >= 2k :

Consider n-1 digit slots, first k and last k digits are reserved. So we have n-1-2k digit slots to fill. Therefore, we would have 10^{n-1-2k} numbers which satisfy the conditions.

Similarly, for n-2 digit numbers, we would have 10^{n-2-2k} numbers and ....We do this until n-1<2k.

2- now we have to consider 2 more things :

A) all n-digit numbers less than or equal to N which satisfy the condition

B) all numbers with less than 2k-digits that satisfy the conditions.

I got stuck in part A) and part B).  and I'm not sure whether my algorithm is correct or not.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Consider M=121212. Then 12121212 starts with M and ends with M.